# How to capitalize only the first letter of each word while keeping acronyms capitalized?

Tags: r, string, stringr, capitalization

I am writing a function to automate variable name cleaning to make homogenous variable names. Typically converting something like 'This is anExample' to 'This.Is.An.Example'. Normally all of that is quite easy, however I am having trouble with acronyms contained within variable names.

An example being this: "Clock in Time PST" would ideally become "Clock.In.Time.PST"

I looked into modifying str_to_upper as a function, but I have no working knowledge of C which appears to be the background of what stringi is written in.

My only next thought is to do something with a conditional checking if a string has no spaces or punctuation then insert the space before the capital letter given the prior letter is lower case. That is my only real thought how to to potentially handle it.

```r
Example<-c("Easy Example Test", 
           "Medium..example TEst", 
           "HaRd exampleTEST", 
           "Truly HARd TestCase  PST")


#Step 1 - Removes all punctuation replacing with spaces
Example<-stringr::str_replace_all(Example, "[[:punct:]]", " ")

#Step 2 - This inserts a space wherever an uppercase letter is found with a preceding lowercase letter.
Example<-stringr::str_replace_all(Example,
 "([[:lower:]](?=[[:upper:]])|[[:upper:]](?=[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]))",
              "\\1 ")

#Step 3 - This replaces all consecutive spaces with a period
Example<-stringr::str_replace_all(names(df), "\\s{1,}", ".")





Current.Outcome<-c("Easy.Example.Test", 
                   "Medium.example.T.Est", 
                   "Ha.Rd.example.TEST", 
                   "Truly.HA.Rd.Test.Case.PST")


Ideal.Outcome<-c("Easy.Example.Test",
                 "Medium.Example.Test", 
                 "Hard.Example.Test", 
                 "Truly.Hard.Test.Case.PST")
```

Comment: I guess there might be dupes for this

Comment: There very well could be similar questions, if I find something that would cover it I will update. A lot of things I found were regarding the str_to_title function which wouldn't be an effective solution.

Comment: To identify an acronym you're going by a word that's all in caps and separated from others by spaces or punctuation? So PST in TestCasePST is not an acronym?

Comment: That would be an ideal outcome, but not required for an initial version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a while figuring out the best general rules to have a solution for this using regular expression rules and string replacement. The solution isn't very pretty but it works in most cases and a more accurate answer wouldn't be as general as I need this to be. An additional example with my working answer is below.

I tried to apply the regular expression splitting over three separate str_replace_all() commands however the results were not promising, thus we have this massive regular expression doing the grouping and matching required.

```r
Example<-c("Easy Example Test", 
           "Medium..example TEst", 
           "Hard exampleTEST", 
           "Truly HARd TestCase  PST",
           "AnotherTESTof5FT2In",
           "AnotherTESTof5FTT2In",
           "ExampleOfCommonProblem")


  Example<-stringr::str_replace_all(Example, "[[:punct:]]", " ")

  Example<-stringr::str_replace_all(Example,
"(([[:lower:]]|[[:digit:]]){1}(?=[[:upper:]])|[[:upper:]]{2,}(?=([[:lower:]]|[[:digit:]]))|([[:lower:]]){1,}(?=[[:digit:]]))",
              "\\1 ")

  Example<-stringr::str_replace_all(Example, "\\s{1,}", ".")

  Example
```

Below is the console output from the code above which doesn't provide a perfect answer, but solves a strong majority of test cases.

```r
>   Example
[1] "Easy.Example.Test"          "Medium.example.TE.st"      
[3] "Hard.example.TEST"          "Truly.HAR.d.Test.Case.PST" 
[5] "Another.TEST.of.5.FT.2.In"  "Another.TEST.of.5.FTT.2.In"
[7] "Example.Of.Common.Problem"
```